# R - ordering a barplot/histogram generated from a data frame

Tags: r, plot, histogram, r-factor

How do I change the order of bars for a barplot generated from a data frame?

I tried code from here:
[R - ordering in boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260698/r-ordering-in-boxplot/4260937#4260937)
but it seems to only work for boxplots, e.g.

```
foo=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c("a","b","c"))
barplot(height=foo$a,names.arg=foo$b)
boxplot(foo$a~foo$b)
foo$c=factor(foo$b,c("c","b","a"))
barplot(height=foo$a,names.arg=foo$c)
boxplot(foo$a~foo$c)
```

Comment: It's not that it only works for boxplots, it's that the two functions use different criteria for determining the order of the x-axis. Boxplot does what most functions do and takes the factor "c" as the x-axis. When you do this, the values will print out according to the order of the levels of the factor. Note that you're just passing a vector of heights to `barplot` so those heights print in whatever order you pass them in. `names.arg` only deals with how they are named, not the order they are drawn. There is nothing in the `heights` parameter is aware of the factor "c".

Comment: Hmm... this seems quite obvious now that you mention it.  Does `barplot` simply not recognize data frames and similar structures?

Comment: Alas it does not. It does not have a formula interface as most other plotting functions do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
foo$c=factor(foo$b, levels = c("c","b","a"))
foo <- foo[order(foo$c), ]
barplot(height=foo$a,names.arg=foo$c)
```

Comment: This answer might do.  I'm still curious as to whether there's a way of doing this without editing the data frame (or generating a new data frame), so I'm going to leave the question open for a bit.

Comment: Ok, thinking about this more, I realize that there's probably not a better way of doing this than either your suggestion or using your subscript-indexing method for each input vector.  Thanks for your help!