# How can I change the order of the discrete x-axis for a beeswarm plot?

Tags: r

I'm using [`beeswarm`](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/) to plot my data.

```
d<-data.frame(Cond=c(WT,WT,KO,KO),Count=c(1,2,3,4))
beeswarm(Count ~ Cond, data = d)
```

This produces the following image.

[image]

How can I manually specify the x-axis, so that WT comes before KO?

Comment: Make it into a factor and set the levels accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that my r knowledge is next to nothing. Could you please write some specific code that I can try?

Comment: Yep, it was a dupe. I just didn't know what to search for. FWIW the answers below worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d<-data.frame(Cond=c("WT","WT","KO","KO"),Count=c(1,2,3,4))

#turn into a factor with manual specification of levels
d$Cond <- factor(d$Cond,levels=c("WT","KO"))


#plot
beeswarm(Count ~ Cond, data = d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was a lot about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260698/r-ordering-in-boxplot)

```
d<-data.frame(Cond=c('WT', 'WT', 'KO', 'KO'),Count=c(1,2,3,4))
    library(beeswarm)

    beeswarm(Count ~ Cond, data = d)

    f <- ordered(d$Cond, levels = c("WT", "KO"))
    beeswarm(Count ~ f, data = d)
```